# Not able to get reasonable results from DenseVariational

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-probability

I am trying a regression problem with the following dataset (sinusoidal curve) of size `500`

[image: Dataset]

First, I tried with 2 dense layer with 10 units each

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='tanh'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='tanh'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
        tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=1.))
    ])
```

Trained with negative log likelihood loss as follows

```py
model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss=neg_log_likelihood)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=50)
```

Resulting plot
[image: Without uncertainty]

Next, I tried similar environment with `DenseVariational`

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
            10, activation='tanh', make_posterior_fn=posterior,
            make_prior_fn=prior, kl_weight=1/N, kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
            10, activation='tanh', make_posterior_fn=posterior,
            make_prior_fn=prior, kl_weight=1/N, kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
            1, activation='tanh', make_posterior_fn=posterior,
            make_prior_fn=prior, kl_weight=1/N, kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=1.))
    ])
```

As the number of parameters approximately double with this, I have tried increasing dataset size and/or epoch size up to 100 times with no success. Results are usually as follows.

[image: With uncertainty]

My questions is how do I get comparable results as that of `Dense` layer with `DenseVariational`? I have also read that it can be sensitive to initial values. [Here](https://gist.github.com/vmg27/ca263b8841fd57ef487f3ee1f5d3b7cc) is the link to full code. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a different surrogate posterior.
In Tensorflow's Bayesian linear regression example
https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Probabilistic_Layers_Regression.ipynb#scrollTo=VwzbWw3_CQ2z

you have the posterior mean field as such

```
# Specify the surrogate posterior over `keras.layers.Dense` `kernel` and `bias`.
def posterior_mean_field(kernel_size, bias_size=0, dtype=None):
  n = kernel_size + bias_size
  c = np.log(np.expm1(1.))
  return tf.keras.Sequential([
      tfp.layers.VariableLayer(2 * n, dtype=dtype),
      tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Independent(
          tfd.Normal(loc=t[..., :n],
                     scale=1e-5 + 0.01*tf.nn.softplus(c + t[..., n:])),
          reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)),
  ])
```

but note that I have included 0.01 in front of the Softplus, reducing the size of the standard deviation.
Try this out.

Even better than this is to use a sampled initialization like the one used as default in the DenseFlipout https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/layers/DenseFlipout?version=nightly

Here's the same initializer but ready for DenseVariational:

```
def random_gaussian_initializer(shape, dtype):
    n = int(shape / 2)
    loc_norm = tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0., stddev=0.1)
    loc = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=loc_norm(shape=(n,), dtype=dtype)
    )
    scale_norm = tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=-3., stddev=0.1)
    scale = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=scale_norm(shape=(n,), dtype=dtype)
    )
    return tf.concat([loc, scale], 0)
```

Now you can just change the VariableLayer in the posterior mean field to

```
tfp.layers.VariableLayer(2 * n, dtype=dtype, initializer=lambda shape, dtype: random_gaussian_initializer(shape, dtype), trainable=True)
```

You are now sampling from a normal distribution with mean -3 and stddev 0.1 to feed into your softplus. Using the mean we have for the posterior mean field scale=Softplus(-3) = 0,048587352, so it's pretty small. With the sampling we will initialize all the scales differently but around that mean.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Perd. I was not able to make it work with tanh activation. However, with relu and further fine tuning, I was able get good results.

Comment: You might also want to try a non-mean field approach with a full covariance. Will take longer to converge, but should be more flexible as it includes the correlations between the distributions. So as the cov matrix is symmetric tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalTriL should be the right choice in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Perd 's answer. I experimented with lower standard deviation on posterior.

For this data and NN architecture, with `tanh` activation, I was not able to get better results. However, I was able to get best results with `relu` activation and `scale=1e-5 + 0.001 * tf.nn.softplus(c + t[..., n:]))`

The model seems to be very sensitive to hyperparameters. Below are the results for different posterior `scale` values

For `scale=1e-5 + 0.01 * tf.nn.softplus(c + t[..., n:]))`
[image: 0.01]

For `scale=1e-5 + 0.005 * tf.nn.softplus(c + t[..., n:]))`
[image: 0.005]

For `scale=1e-5 + 0.002 * tf.nn.softplus(c + t[..., n:]))`
[image: 0.002]

For `scale=1e-5 + 0.0015 * tf.nn.softplus(c + t[..., n:]))`
[image: 0.0015]

For `scale=1e-5 + 0.001 * tf.nn.softplus(c + t[..., n:]))`
[image: 0.001]

For `tanh` activation, still not able to get good results
[image: tanh]

[Code Link](https://gist.github.com/vmg27/7ee4ad69597796a9ea4ce14b08749ad3)

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem and it took me a while to realize the cause.

Your last layer in the Dense-NN has no activation function (tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)) while your last layer in the Variational-NN has tanh as activation (tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
1, *activation='tanh'* ...).
Removing this should fix the problem.
I also observed that relu and especially leaky-relu are superior to tanh in this setting.

Comment: Thank you @bayes2021. Nice catch. Tried it. Still not able get good results with `tanh` though.

Comment: @VijayGiri maybe the `snake` activation function could be of interest. [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/activations/snake). I've also had problems with the DenseVariational Layer in combination with periodic functions and nearly all activation functions.